# How to get all the items in both lists even when items not existing in both lists?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two enumerable lists.

```
List<List_Data> List1 = new List<List_Data>();
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "1", Batch = "B1", QTY = 5 });
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "1", Batch = "B2", QTY = 5 });
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "2", Batch = "B1", QTY = 15 });

List<List_Data> List2 = new List<List_Data>();
List2.Add(new List_Data { Material = "1", Batch = "B1", QTY = 2 });
List2.Add(new List_Data { Material = "3", Batch = "B1", QTY = 5 });
List2.Add(new List_Data { Material = "3", Batch = "B2", QTY = 15 });
```

What i want is to compare the two lists and get the difference QTY (list1.QTY  - list2.QTY) base on material and batch. Even if a item not exist on the other list i need to get minus or plus qty base on that material and batch.

This is the out put i'm expecting.

```
Material = "1", Batch = "B1", QTY = 3
Material = "1", Batch = "B2", QTY = 5 
Material = "2", Batch = "B1", QTY = 15
Material = "3", Batch = "B1", QTY = -5
Material = "3", Batch = "B2", QTY = -15
```

This is what i done so far,

```
SendList = (from l1 in List1
            join l2 in List2 on new { l1.Material, l1.Batch } equals new { l2.Material, l2.Batch } into temp
            from l2 in temp.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new Report_Class
            {
                Material = l1.Material != null ? l1.Material : l2.Material, 
                Batch = l1.Batch != null ? l1.Batch : l2.Batch, 
                Difference = l1 != null && l2 != null ? (l1.QTY - l2.QTY).ToString() : l1 != null ? l1.QTY.ToString() : l2.QTY.ToString(), 

            }).ToList();
```

problem is it returns the list1 all items that exists, but not returns the item only exists in list 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You need Concat, GroupBy and Select

Comment: Typo: Your output says `QTY` but your select statement has `Difference`. Also, it would be good to use more meaningful variable names than `List1` and `List2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one approach:

- Reverse the `QTY` values on List2
- Concatenate the result of the above with List1.
- Group the concatenated list by `Material` and `Batch`, and sum up the `QTY` values

Here it is in code:

```
var result = List1.Concat(
             List2.Select(list2Item => new List_Data
             {
                 Material = list2Item.Material,
                 Batch = list2Item.Batch,
                 QTY = list2Item.QTY * -1
             }))
             .GroupBy(item => new { item.Material, item.Batch })
             .Select(grouped => new List_Data
             {
                 Material = grouped.First().Material,
                 Batch = grouped.First().Batch,
                 QTY = grouped.Sum(item => item.QTY)
             })
             .ToList();
```

Even if you have null `QTY`, it will still work. For example, having these values:

```
List<List_Data> List1 = new List<List_Data>();
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "1", Batch = "B1", QTY = 5 });
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "1", Batch = "B2", QTY = 5 });
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "2", Batch = "B1", QTY = 15 });
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "3", Batch = "B1", QTY = null });
List1.Add(new List_Data { Material = "3", Batch = "B3", QTY = 4 });

List<List_Data> List2 = new List<List_Data>();
List2.Add(new List_Data { Material = "1", Batch = "B1", QTY = 2 });
List2.Add(new List_Data { Material = "3", Batch = "B1", QTY = 5 });
List2.Add(new List_Data { Material = "3", Batch = "B2", QTY = 15 });
List2.Add(new List_Data { Material = "3", Batch = "B3", QTY = null });
```

will result to:

```
Material: "1", Batch: "B1", QTY: 3
Material: "1", Batch: "B2", QTY: 5
Material: "2", Batch: "B1", QTY: 15
Material: "3", Batch: "B1", QTY: -5
Material: "3", Batch: "B3", QTY: 4
Material: "3", Batch: "B2", QTY: -15
```

Comment: Yes it did. Thank you

Comment: @FrankFajardo very nice solution (+1) from me.

Comment: Thank you @Christos. I appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 1):

If we **assume** that in the second list there would be at most (if at all) one element with the same `Material` and `Bacth` value, then a naive solution could be the following:

```
// Initially project each element in the list to an element that 
// has also the info in which list this item is contained.
var list1 = List1.Select(x => new {Data = x, List = 1});
var list2 = List2.Select(x => new {Data = x, List = 2});

var result = list1.Concat(list2)
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.Data.Batch, x.Data.Material})
            .Select(gr =>
            {
                var itemsInGroup = gr.Count();
                if (itemsInGroup == 1)
                {
                    var onlyItemInGroup = gr.First();

                    if (onlyItemInGroup.List == 1)
                    {
                        return onlyItemInGroup.Data;
                    }

                    // Item came from the second list. So multiply it's quantity by -1.
                    onlyItemInGroup.Data.QTY *= -1;

                    return onlyItemInGroup.Data;
                }

                // Since for each item in list 1 there is at most one item in the list2
                // and vice versa itemsInGroup now is 2 and it is safe to use First as below
                // to grab the items.

                var itemFromFirstList = gr.First(x => x.List == 1);
                var itemFromSecondList = gr.First(x => x.List == 2);

                return new List_Data
                {
                    Material = gr.Key.Material,
                    Batch = gr.Key.Batch,
                    QTY = itemFromFirstList.Data.QTY - itemFromSecondList.Data.QTY
                };
            }).ToList();
```

Essentially all the work is done inside the `Select` after we have concatenated the two list and grouped the items in the resulting list based on the key `Material` and `Batch`. The options we have based on the initially assumption are the following:

- The group contains only one item and this item is from the first list. In this case we just return the Data that this item contains.
- The group contains only one item and this item is from the second list. In this case we have to multiply the value `QTY` with -1. Remember that the type you want to use is the `list1.QTY - list2.QTY` and there isn't any associated element in the first list, `list1`. So you want to get `-list2.QTY` as you have declared.
- The group contains two items and **since** we have assumed that there would be  at most (if at all) one associated element in one list for another element in the other. In this case, we have just to subtract `list2.QTY` from `list1.QTY` to get the new quantity.

Comment: hi, thank you for answering the question, but  im getting an error in ' item.Data.QTY *= -1; ' , Property or indexer 'AnonymousType#1.QTY' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

Comment: @DinukshiJayarathne You are welcome. Hm...I executed the code and I didn't spot this issue. By the way, after the initialization of `List2` you have to use `List2.Add` and not `List1.Add`. Please correct also this and let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution

```
var result = List1
    .Select(e => new        
    {
        key = new
        {
            e.Material, 
            e.Batch
        }, 
        QTY = e.QTY
    })
    .Concat(List2
        .Select(e => new
        {
            key = new
            {
                e.Material, 
                e.Batch
            }, 
            QTY = -e.QTY
        }))
    .GroupBy( e => e.key, e => e.QTY )
    .Select(g => new Report_Class
    {
        Material = g.Key.Material, 
        Batch = g.Key.Batch, 
        Difference = g.Sum()
    })
    .ToList();
```

[.net fiddle sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zd0Lhf)